# Need help how to call an api from a plugin on .net Core (nonncommerce)

Tags: .net-core

I need a little help here. I'm trying to call an api from a plugin on .net core if someone can help me with that I'll very grateful.

Comment: Need more details. What kind of API? Http? Websockets? Also, when you say "plugin" you mean a .net library project?

Comment: A rest api and just plugin.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include additional details and, if possible, a minimum compilable example showing your work.